# Zend pdf errors with function Image drawing

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-pdf

I want to put image to my pdf file from code function in zend that i get simple example from here http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.drawing.html and this is my code

```
    $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath("' . $base . '/images/logo1.png");
    $page->drawImage($image, 100, 100, 400, 300);
    // add page to document
    $pdf->pages[] = $page;
    $pdf->save("data/reports/-report.pdf");
```

but i get errors like this

```
PDF error: Cannot create image resource. File not found.
```

any help with it. thanks

Comment: whats the value of $base

Comment: `$base` is path to image of my project

Comment: `$image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath("images/logo1.png");` will solve the problem if there are appropriate file permissions.

Comment: @koe Is your issue resolved? if yes, then can we tell me how did u resolved this. I am getting same erro

Answer (score 1):

your including single quotes inside a file name.

```
$image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath("' . $base . '/images/logo1.png");
```

change it so it reads

```
$image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($base . "/images/logo1.png");
```

Comment: Thanks but i think it's not problem with this, anyways i have test with it already but still the same errors :)

Comment: then you must be providing a incorrect path, make sure you provide absolute path

Comment: Ok, and what if php can not read you image, because permission problems? Check the file permissions